# Informatica and 3rd Party Version Control: Good Idea?

Tags: version-control, informatica

I'm aware that you can enable Informatica's own brand of version control for repository mappings/objects and this seems to work reasonably well, if developers don't mind the encumbrance of checking mappings/objects out using the tool.

My question is it considered a good/bad idea to run git (or a 3rd party vc of your choice) on the repository xml directly, outside of the tool control?

Comment: How will it less annoying to export all the modified objects into separate XML files, commit the changes and push them to a central repository?

Comment: My original thought was that the XML was available in file structures, on the Informatica hosts.  I didn't expect it to explicitly identify objects by name, but the version control could be applied to that directory structure and changes tracked via weekly commits.  If all of the XML has to be explicitly exported from the repository, this would not be a viable solution.

Comment: The repository is a set of tables in a relational database. There is a documentation that describes the Metadata Exchange views but their structure is so complex that I would dare to use them to extract the XML files myself.

Answer (score 1):

The idea once came up in our discussions as well. We discarded it because of the overhead involved in exporting and importing the repository xmls.

Comment: Can you briefly elaborate the overheads?